# Finding the nearest Apollonian gasket

Tags: discrete-geometry

Given a set $\mathcal{P}$ of $n$ points in the euclidean plane, how can a set $\mathcal{V}$ of $n$ vectors be determined, that has minimal length-sum and renders $\lbrace p_i+v_i\rbrace$ to be the centers of the circles of an [Apollonian gasket](https://www.americanscientist.org/article/a-tisket-a-tasket-an-apollonian-gasket), i.e. so that it is possible to choose $\lbrace r_i\rbrace$ so that the disks with radius $r_i$ do not overlap when centered at $p_i+v_i$ and cover all edges of these center's Delaunay triangulation?